# JAVA+Mongodb: $pull with pattern list

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

In compass, below script can work:

```
db.documentName.updateMany({}, {$pull:{arrayField:{$in:[/^aaa$/i,/^bbb$/i]}}})
```

Could please help how to realize this operation in JAVA spring boot application?

The Document like

```
{
    "_id": "003",
    "arrayField": [
        "AaA",
        "BbB",
        "AAaa"
    ]
}
```

I tried to use mongoTemplate.pullAll

```
Query query=new Query();
Update update = new Update();
update.pullAll("arrayField", new String[]{"/^aaa$/i", "/^bbb$/i"});
mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, entityClass);
```

or

```
update.pullAll("arrayField", new Pattern[]{Pattern.compile("aaa", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE),
                Pattern.compile("bbb", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)});
```

But it doesn't work:(

Comment: did you try the example from [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/usage-examples/updateMany/)